# MySQL GROUP BY Doesn't effect

Tags: mysql

My query is like the following:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY category
```

The total returned is the total of all posts, Can some one please point me where is the issue in my syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The total returned is the total of all posts* - Are sure about that? Also, what do you want to be returned?

Answer (score 5):

I think the correct would be:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY category;
```